# Can some one discuss these interview Question regarding permission?

Tags: linux, centos, permissions, non-root-user

Effective user id can be set using following permission? 4744
Effective group id can be set using following permission? 2666

Hi, guys reading some interview question and I got some interview stuff online.
I have posted this stuff due to I am not getting on any other books and sites.
So I need some information regarding What is meant by Effective user id and Effective group id. Here are some question and answer are given.

As I know umask for root and normal user are different.
Root user  Directory    0022
           Files        0133

Normal user Directory   0002
            files       0113
Ok! As I want to know weather SUID and SGID has its permission value setted. 
I am not getting

Comment: I can't tell from this what it is you're actually asking. Are you looking for just a tutorial, or is there something specific the relevant manual pages etc. don't tell? About EUID, see e.g. [Difference between Real User ID, Effective User ID and Saved User ID on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32455684/6372809).

Answer (score 1):

When a process is launched it has 4 identifiers related to users and groups:

- `User ID` (`UID`): The `UID` of the user that is launching the process.
- `Group ID` (`GID`):  The primary `GID` of the user that is launching the process.
- `Effective User ID` (`EUID`): Usually it is set to the `UID`, except if the SetUID bit of the file holding the program is set to 1. In this case `EUID` is the ID of the owner file.
- `Effective Group ID` (`EGID`): Usually it is set to the `GID`, except if the `SetGID` bit of the file holding the program file is 1. In this case, `GID` is set to the ID of the group the file belongs.

The permissions applied to the process are always based on the `EUID` and `EGID`.

The `SetUID` and `SetGID` mechanisms allow for a user to invoke actions with higher privileges, without using other elevation mechanisms. As an example, the  `ping` tool can actually open a `SOCKET_RAW`, even if normal users do not have the capability of using those sockets.

This can also be applied to folders, but it changes the permissions of the files written to that folder (`SetGID`).

This can only be applied (with success) to binary files. Applying the `SetUID` bit to a script achieves nothing as the permissions are set by the interpreter (the binary file), and not the script.

Comment: Thank you very much. Well I have forgotten SUID and GUID is also set by numerically.